# UINavigationController initWithRootViewController, view not appearing

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uitableview

I'm trying to get a navigation based feature to display different table views with no luck. Essentially the view used for `initWithRootViewController` is not being displayed properly, but the navigation bar is. Here's the code within the `viewDidLoad` method of `TimerViewController` with hierarchy `AppDelegate` -> `ViewController` -> `TimerViewController`:

```
incidentTableViewController = [[IncidentTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [incidentTableViewController.tableView.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:172.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [incidentTableViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 268, 423)];
    [incidentTableViewController.tableView showsVerticalScrollIndicator];
    [incidentTableViewController setTitle:@"Incidents"];
    [incidentTableViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:incidentTableViewController];
    [controller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(268, 0, 268, 423)];
    [controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
    //[controller.view addSubview:incidentTableViewController.view];
    [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

this results with (I'm not sure why there is a gap above the navigation bar either):

[image]

If I uncomment the second from last line `[controller.view addSubview:incidentTableViewController.view];` I get this result which is as required minus the navigation bar:

[image]

What I want to achieve is have the second image with a navigation bar, any ideas?

Comment: in which method do you write your code, in appDelegate? or do you want to display your view with navigation on the click?

Comment: The code is written in another class with hierarchy `AppDelegate` -> `ViewController` -> `TimerViewController` within the `viewDidLoad` method of `TimerViewController`.

Comment: what do you want achieve? the viewcontroller with bar, how it's called? when you click a button?

Comment: I want the second image to be displayed (the table view displayed correctly) with a navigation bar

Comment: this view with toolbar is your initial view(when the app starts you see it first)?

Comment: if the view with toolbar is not your initial view then how do you show it? (as a modalview)?

Comment: The application is tab bar based, so when a particular tab is pressed I simply call `[centralArea bringSubviewToFront:splitViewController.view];` (if the view has already been initialised)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by using a `UISplitViewController` initialised with the navigation controller as its view controller, the working code is as follows:

```
incidentTableViewController = [[IncidentTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:incidentTableViewController];
    incidentTableViewController.title = @"Incidents";
    splitViewController = [[UISplitViewController alloc] init];
    splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:controller, nil];
    splitViewController.delegate = (id)incidentTableViewController;
    splitViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(268, 0, 268, 423);
    [self.view addSubview:splitViewController.view];
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing this?

```
[controller.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

btw, in your appdidfinishlaunching of your appDelegate do this:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

incidentTableViewController = [[IncidentTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

[incidentTableViewController.tableView.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:172.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
[incidentTableViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 268, 423)];
[incidentTableViewController.tableView showsVerticalScrollIndicator];
[incidentTableViewController setTitle:@"Incidents"];
[incidentTableViewController.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:incidentTableViewController];
[controller.view setFrame:CGRectMake(268, 0, 268, 423)];
[controller.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
self.window.rootViewController = incidentTableViewController;

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

if your window has a rootViewcontroller, then you either should push the incidentTableViewController on to the nav stack or present the incidentTableViewController modally

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, I don't want this particular view to appear when the application launches

Comment: in that case, you'll need to do the same, without adding it to the window, but by pushing the view controller onto the navigation stack or by presenting the viewcontroller modally. If you are using a navigation controller just for the bar, then you can use UIToolbar instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the logic of your project. You can start a new tab project and modify the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method
Here I show the example with 2 tabs, one tab with sample view and another with toolbar:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    //view controller for 1st tab
    UIViewController * viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];

    //your view controller with bar for the 2d tab
    IncidentTableViewController *incidentTableViewController = [[IncidentTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    [incidentTableViewController.tableView.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:167.0/255.0 green:169.0/255.0 blue:172.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
    [incidentTableViewController.tableView showsVerticalScrollIndicator];
    [incidentTableViewController setTitle:@"Incidents"];
    UINavigationController *controller = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:incidentTableViewController];

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, controller, nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the changes aren't having any effect

Answer (score 0):

UINavigationController Do not have your customized view.

```
 [self.view addSubview:controller.view];
```

--->

```
 [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

or

```
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

Comment: Sorry. Not [self.view ...] --> [self ...]